# Why Cura refuse to slice this object?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, 3d-models, dremel-3d45

I downloaded this [SpaceNavErgoStand_for Space Navigator NB USB](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1513491) from Thingiverse. But Cura 5.3.1 refuses to slice it:

[image: Screenshot of a 3D model in Cura]

I'm aware I can file a bug report, but before I'm kindly asking here if there is something obvious I missed. Of course, I tried to change a lot of settings, but it never sliced it.

To be clear, the failure happened with the printer Dremel 3D45 as reported in the tag. Using another printer, like Sovol SV04 there are no errors.

Here are the machine settings. As said, they are the default ones. I didn't change anything. And I also tried to install Cura and the Dremel printer on a new PC. Same behavior.

[image: The Dremel 3D45 printer settings inside of Cura]

[image: The Dremel 3D45 extruder settings inside of Cura]

Comment: I was able to slice the file with Cura 5.3.1 on a Mac without any warnings/problems. Have you tried reinstalling Cura?

Comment: @agarza did you slice it using Dremel 3D45 printer?

Comment: No, but I don't think that would matter. Have you tried slicing for a different printer?

Comment: @agarza, yes. It works. Perhaps it's not so clear in the question, I'm going to update it.

Comment: I recommend making your "edit" an actual answer. This will provide future visitors to see how you solved the problem. After 24 hrs of posting, you can accept your own answer as the solution.

Comment: @agarza I didn't solved it at all! I need to print it on my Dremel. I still don't know how to fix.

Comment: it *sounds* to me like the profile for the Dremel might be defective. Can you share the details of the profile?

Comment: @Trish, of course! Actually, which details do you need? I didn't change the settings of the printer. Or are you talking about the slicer settings?

Comment: The machine settings in the slicer.  have you tried just RE-creating the machine in case the machine settings are borked?

Comment: @Trish, as said the settings are the default ones. I tried to install Cura and the Dremel printer on a different PC but the behavior is the same. Anyway, I updated the question with the information requested.

Comment: Have you tried an earlier version of Cura? maybe even back to version 4?

Comment: @agarza, no I didn't. Even if it turns out it works, I don't want to use such an older version. I'd like to understand how to fix in the latest version.

Comment: If the older version works, then you will have determined that the newer profile has an issue. You may even be able to take the old profile and use it with Cura 5.3.1.

Comment: @agarza, well I tried Cura 4.13.1 but the Dremel plugin was not available. Cura 5.0.0 can slice the object, but the machine settings are the same. Now, how can you be sure is the profile instead of the actual code in Cura 5.3.1?

Comment: The only way is to try it. It is all a process of elimination.

Comment: @agarza sorry, try what? I only know in 5.0.0 it slices, in 5.3.1 does not.

Comment: Try moving the Dremel profile from an older version of Cura to 5.3.1.

Comment: Copied `Dremel3D45.def.json` from 5.0.0 to 5.3.1. It does not slice. Anyway, the files are identical.